# Jansy Bootstrap image upload user avatar - when editing a user

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Jansy's Bootstrap for uploading user avatars through my admin control panel, like in the example here: http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput-examples .

When adding a new user it's all good, but what about when editing a user and I need the user's avatar to show in the plugin by default, so basically I need the state of the image upload plugin to be like after I choose a picture.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible and you achieve this with JavaScript (jQuery)!

So, when you are on your `edit user page` you need to have the user data (id, name, ... , avatar). You need the avatar.extension in order to populate the input file. (ex. picture1.jpg) This is not a problem because this data is stored in your database.

Considering that you keep your image name in an javascript `avatar` variable, and your input type file name is `avatar`, all you need to do is to add this piece of code in your file:

```
var avatar="user_avatar.jpg";

if (avatar != '') {
    $('.fileinput').addClass('fileinput-exists').removeClass('fileinput-new');
    $('.fileinput-filename').html(avatar);
}
```

With this code you change the `add state` into an `edit state` for this customized fileinput.

I even made an example for you to prove that this works, you can check it [here](http://ileapaulalexandru.ro/jansy/).

You can even try to make an image upload on that example to see that after the page refresh you will see the `edit state` for that upload. You can also inspect the code with firebug in case you don't understand something or even ask me.